# Adding Elements to a Vector Array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, vector

So I am having trouble adding the divisors I find through a loop into a vector array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector <int> numbers;

bool isSummableNumber(int num)
{
    for (int i=1; i<=num; i++)
    {
        if (num%i==0)
            {
                 // this is where I need to send them to the array 
            }
    }
```

In my int main() I have requested the user enter a number and through that loop, I find all the divisors and then I am having trouble adding them to the array.

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/7fthz5xd.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried: `numbers.push_back(num)`?

Comment: @bolov: How in the world is `push_back` "convoluted?"  Were you just being sarcastic?

Comment: Too subtle I guess. Yes, I was being sarcastic.

Answer (score 0):

For adding an element to a `vector`, you simply have to call:

```
vector_name.push_back( element_value );
```

so in your case:

```
bool isSummableNumber(int num)
{
    for (int i=1; i<=num; i++)
    {
        if (num%i==0)
            {
                 numbers.push_back( num );
            }
    }
}
```